# Checking for a values existence: slice iteration vs map lookups in Go

Tags: performance, comparative-review, go, hash-map

Assuming I have the following slice:

```
mySlice := []string{"one", "two", "three"}
```

and I want to know whether or not it contains a given string, say `"three"`.

I could iterate over each entry:

```
for i, v := range mySlice {
  if v == "three" {
    return i
  }
}
```

But I could also convert the slice to a map:

```
myMap := make(map[string]string)
for i, v := range mySlice {
  myMap[v] = i
}

if v, ok := myMap["three"]; ok {
  // three exists in original slice
}
```

I think that the first is faster than the second for a single lookup, but at what point does the second method become faster? Would converting to a map be more performant if I'm doing 2 or more lookups? Or does it depend on the size of the array?

Comment: please see https://forum.golangbridge.org/t/how-about-performance-of-map-against-slice/4415